# How to unit test multipart/form-data with moq in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, moq, multipartform-data

I have been trying to write a unit test for the method of service which gets multiple/form-data from the Request. Here is my method:

```
var boundary = MultipartRequestHelper.GetBoundary(
                   MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.ContentType),
                   DEFAULT_MULTIPART_BOUNDARY_LENGTH_LIMIT);

                var reader = new MultipartReader(boundary, HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Body);
                var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
                var streamedFileContent = Array.Empty<byte>();
                var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                while (section != null)
                {
                    var hasContentDispositionHeader =
                    ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse(
                        section.ContentDisposition, out var contentDisposition);

                    if (hasContentDispositionHeader)
                    {
                        if (MultipartRequestHelper.HasFileContentDisposition(contentDisposition))
                        {
                            streamedFileContent = await FileHelpers.ProcessStreamedFile(
                            section, contentDisposition, Configuration.GetFileSizeLimit());
                        }
                        else if (MultipartRequestHelper.HasFormDataContentDisposition(contentDisposition))
                        {
                            var key = HeaderUtilities
                                 .RemoveQuotes(contentDisposition.Name).Value;
                            var encoding = GetEncoding(section);

                            if (encoding == null)
                                throw new ErrorCodeException("error-invalid-data");

                            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(
                                section.Body,
                                encoding,
                                detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: true,
                                bufferSize: 1024,
                                leaveOpen: true))
                            {
                                var value = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
                                dictionary.Add(key, value);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
                }

                var file = new File
                {
                    AuthorId = authorStaffId,
                    Name = dictionary.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Key == "name").Value,
                    Size = streamedFileContent.Length,
                    Extension = dictionary.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Key == "extension").Value,
                    MimeType = dictionary.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Key == "mimeType").Value,
                    IsTemporary = true,
                    FileId = Guid.NewGuid()
                };
                file = await SaveFileContentAsync(streamedFileContent, file);
                file.ContentHash = CanculateContentHash(streamedFileContent);
                await _fileRepository.AddAsync(file);
```

Here I am trying to send a request from the Postman and this way it is working fine:
[image: Sending request from the Postman]

And following way I am trying to test my code with xUnit and Moq:

```
        [Fact]
        public async Task UploadFileAsync_WhenFileSizeIsNotBiggerThanLimit_Successful()
        {
            // Arrange
            ConfigureClaims();
            ConfigureDatabase();
            ConfigureService();

            var fakeFileContent = GetFakeFileContent();
            var byteContent = Convert.FromBase64String(fakeFileContent); 

            Stream stream = new MemoryStream(byteContent);
            _moqHttpContextAccessor.Setup(x => x.HttpContext.Request.Body).Returns(stream);
            _moqHttpContextAccessor.Setup(x => x.HttpContext.Request.ContentType).Returns("multipart/form-data; boundary=----231179732646258011288433");
            _moqHttpContextAccessor.Setup(x => x.HttpContext.Request.ContentLength).Returns(0x000000000001d74e);

            // Act
            var addedFileId = _baseFileService.UploadFileAsync();
            var addedFile = _fileRepository.GetById(addedFileId);

            // Assert
            Assert.NotNull(addedFile);
        }
```

I got the following error message: **InvalidDataException: Multipart body length limit 16384 exceeded** 
And I tried this way:

```
[Fact]
        public async Task UploadFileAsync_WhenFileSizeIsNotBiggerThanLimit_Successful()
        {
            // Arrange
            ConfigureClaims();
            ConfigureDatabase();
            ConfigureService();

            var fakeFileContent = GetFakeFileContent();
            var byteContent = Convert.FromBase64String(fakeFileContent);

            var byteStringContent = byteContent.ToString();
            var forDataDictionary = new Dictionary<string, StringValues>
            {
                {"file", byteStringContent},
                {"name", "test.pdf"},
                {"size", "120085"},
                {"mimeType", "application/pdf" }
            };
            var formData = new FormCollection(forDataDictionary);
            _moqHttpContextAccessor.Setup(x => x.HttpContext.Request.Form).Returns(formData);

            // Act
            var addedFileId = _baseFileService.UploadFileAsync();
            var addedFile = _fileRepository.GetById(addedFileId);

            // Assert
            Assert.NotNull(addedFile);
        }
```

I got an error because I am not getting the content from Request.Form. I am getting it from Reques.Body

Then I looked around the Web and could not find any proper answer. What can I do here?

Comment: You're trying to mock an HTTP request, not HttpContext. The problem starts from using `HttpContext.Current` to read requests, and depending on `HttpContext` throughout the method. Why not use a proper Web API action instead? If you can't do that (why?), a far better solution would be to extract all the code into a separate method that only accepts the Request as input. You'll be able to test that method by passing a test HttpRequest

Answer (score 1):

you can take this approach to mock your IformFile.

```
public static IFormFile AsValidMockIFormFile(this FileInfo physicalFile)
    {
        var fileMock = new Mock<IFormFile>();
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = new StreamWriter(ms);
        writer.Write(physicalFile.OpenRead());
        writer.Flush();
        ms.Position = 0;
        var fileName = physicalFile.Name;
        //Setup mock file using info from physical file
        fileMock.Setup(_ => _.FileName).Returns(fileName);
        fileMock.Setup(_ => _.Length).Returns(ms.Length);
        fileMock.Setup(m => m.OpenReadStream()).Returns(ms);
        fileMock.Setup(m => m.ContentType).Returns("text/csv");
        fileMock.Setup(m => m.ContentDisposition).Returns(string.Format("inline; filename={0}", fileName));

        return fileMock.Object;
    }
```

As this above method will give a IformFile object. but to decorate the same you need to pass some data(i.e., you need to hold a sample file in your test data)

```
var physicalFile = new FileInfo("filePath.txt"); // Put your sample file here
fakeFileContent = FileHelper.AsValidMockIFormFile(physicalFile);
var info=await _controller.UploadAtion(fakeFileContent) as OkObjectResult;
```